# How to indent multiline text behind lists in QMLs TextEdit

Tags: list, qt, qml, richtext, textedit

In QML Im using a TextEdit item for a text editor with highlighter code running behind it (QSyntaxHighlighter). When the user types a dash (-), it will be recognised by the highlighter code and formatted (like Markdown). But additionally I want the text to be indented behind the dash, when it is multiline. Just like it behaves with HTML lists.

This is how it looks like right now: 
[image: How it looks like right now]

This is how I want it (the text aligns properly behind the dash):
[image]

I know this can indent the text:

```
QTextCursor cursor(currentBlock());
QTextBlockFormat textBlockFormat = currentBlock().blockFormat();
textBlockFormat.setIndent(1);
cursor.setBlockFormat(textBlockFormat);
```

An idea is to indent all the text by default and un-indent the lines with a dash or similar, but couldn't quite figure out yet how to achieve it.

Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Ok apparently there is also a list styling option. This is how you can change the style of a block:

```
QTextBlock block = textDoc->findBlockByNumber(i);
QTextCursor cursor(block);

cursor.beginEditBlock();
QTextListFormat::Style style = QTextListFormat::ListDecimal;
QTextBlockFormat blockFmt = cursor.blockFormat();
QTextListFormat listFmt;

if (cursor.currentList()) {
    listFmt = cursor.currentList()->format();
} else {
    listFmt.setIndent(blockFmt.indent() + 1);
    blockFmt.setIndent(0);
    cursor.setBlockFormat(blockFmt);
}

listFmt.setStyle(style);

cursor.createList(listFmt);
cursor.endEditBlock();
```

This could be used in a slot linking to the contentsChange signal from QTextDocument or in a highlighter.